# Environment variable concatenation and append

Tags: bash

If I have an environment variable:

```
$foo=/my/path/one:/my/path/two
```

How can I set:

```
$bar=${foo}/bin
```

where:

```
$bar=/my/path/one/bin:/my/path/two/bin
```

?

Doing what I have done above only does (not lack of /bin on first path):

```
$bar=/my/path/one/:/my/path/two/bin
```

I can manually set this, or iterate over it in a list, but these seem complicated for no reason. Is there a clever one-liner way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do I see right you would like to have this:

```
foo=$(echo $foo | sed -e 's@:\|$@/bin&@g'); echo $foo
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Not the most robust but perhaps the simplest is to just replace all the colons with `/bin:` using parameter expansion:

```
foo=/my/path/one:/my/path/two:/my/path/three

noo=${foo//:/\/bin:}/bin

echo $noo
/my/path/one/bin:/my/path/two/bin:/my/path/three/bin
```

**Explanation:**

The syntax `${foo}` lets you do many kinds search and replace in the variable. In this case we are using pattern matching, with the patterns separated by slashes. Normally you might do something like this:

```
$(foo/findme/replace}
```

which will look for the string `findme` in `$foo` and replace it with `replace`.

To swap out the colons with `x`, you could search with `${foo/:/x/}` but to replace all and not just the first, you put two slashes at the beginning. To use a slash in the replacement you need to escape it with backslash `\/`

All together, that gives us the pattern used above (spaces added for clarity but they would break it in real life):

```
          <find>   <replace>
${foo  //   :   /   \/bin:  }
```

The rest is history.

Comment: it's not easy for a human to read though :p, but sed isn't that much better either.

Comment: Yes,  the slashes are confusing, but // means replace all